# Проблема с Custom View

Tags: android

Есть кастомный View. При попытке прописать его в xml выбивает

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.antonin.loveterest.drawableview.draw.CanvasDrawer.onDraw_Original(CanvasDrawer.java:26)
    at org.antonin.loveterest.drawableview.draw.CanvasDrawer.onDraw(CanvasDrawer.java)
    at org.antonin.loveterest.drawableview.DrawableView.onDraw_Original(DrawableView.java:112)
    at org.antonin.loveterest.drawableview.DrawableView.onDraw(DrawableView.java)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17067)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16975)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17070)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16975)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17070)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:387)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:498)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:434)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Что это может быть?

Comment: Это ни что иное - как великий и могучий [Null Pointer Exception](https://habrahabr.ru/post/221243/)

Comment: код покажите что ли

Comment: https://github.com/PaNaVTEC/DrawableView. Хочу переделать под свои нужды.

Comment: Без кода не разобраться, покажите хоть что-то. Но судя по всему, это достаточно простая либа, которую можно легко сделать самому. Если Вы разберёте уроки 141-167 на сайте http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html , то легко сможете сделать такую самостоятельно. Не поленитесь и разберитесь, потом будет намного легче ;)